# When are try/exceptions not an anti-pattern?

Tags: design, coding-style, code-quality, exceptions

I just finished a discussion with colleagues regarding the use of exceptions in code.  Here is the code (pseudocode) that they had written:

```py
resp = fetch(URL)
if resp.status_code != 200:
     return False
```

I suggested that they use the below (pseudocode):

```py
try:
    resp.fetch(URL)
except HTTPError as e:
    logging.info("HTTP request failed with error: ", e)
    return False
```

To my surprise, I was met with a lot of resistance.  Evidently, this team has a policy that they almost never use try/except to manage control flow (I am new to the team).  I understand that *is* an anti-pattern in some cases, but here we are actually handling an exceptional (namely, 4xx or 5xx) response.  Also, this is a convention that I have seen used in practically every place I've worked so far.

Does my suggest count as an anti-pattern use of try/except?  When is it a good, or bad, idea?
I realize that there are a number of posts regarding this topic, and I have read through them; I haven't seen anything specific, though, regarding HTTP request/response handling, which I why I post this question.

Comment: often this is a team style preference as either one works. One note is that it's easy to forget to catch some exception that is thrown - except in Java

Comment: When are try/exception an anti-pattern?

Comment: @Christophe I found a lot of resources which declare try/except a discouraged pattern in code...which surprised me, I'll admit.  Although, it seems that the reasons not to use them have to do with managing control flow unnecessarily

Comment: @Daniel while there are antipaterns in these constructs, if used for "exceptional" situations, it is a perfectly valid construct.  You'll also find a lot of obsolete remarks about performance issues related to these constructs.  These date back to the early days of Java and C++ and are no longer relevant.  See for example this  recommendation:  https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Re-errors

Comment: See also here how the exception throwing is exempted to the single exit point rule, including in industrial secure coding standards https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/416677/209774 - See here for an anlalysis of the C++good practices https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/430994/209774 (in the comments, you'll see a discussion on the performance aspects).

Comment: @Christophe thank you that is helpful!

Comment: @Daniel: *"resources which declare try/except a discouraged pattern"* - I don't know any such pattern. Please provide links that explain what you mean.

Comment: @Daniel: The way how you use try/catch makes no sense. You should not catch exception and return boolean. Instead, the exception should be propagated to the higher layers, e.g. to some controller or some REST service. This is the whole idea of exceptions - to make the code shorter and to focus on whenever possible on the *"happy flow"* only.

Comment: @Christophe "You'll also find a lot of obsolete remarks about performance issues related to these constructs." Are you saying that nowadays exceptions are performant?

Comment: @greenoldman with modern C++ compilers, entering a try block has no noticeable performance effect. Throwing is of course more costly due to stack unwinding. This is why exceptions should be use for exceptional cases. --  (I have past measurements of a couple of microseconds for a throw compared to a nanosecond level for a return, but this difference is irrelevant for processing web requests, where you'll work at milisecond level, i.e 1000 times slower than microseconds, and 1000,7 vs 1000,05 will not make the difference)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/39311200/3723423 for performance impact, and when to use exceptions and when not.

Comment: @Christophe, thank you. I don't agree with your conclusion though. IMHO if your design and execution cost is similar you should always chose more performant way. Excusing yourself "that in given context it is irrelevant" piles up.

Comment: The key design question is: *is a web site returning a non-200 code an exceptionally unusual behaviour or a normal behaviour?* If it is an exceptionally unusual behaviour then use an exception handler. If it is a normal behaviour then use normal conditional logic. Exception handlers are called that because they are for handling exceptionally unlikely situations.

Comment: Anti-pattern is not a term that really has any meaning, any more than "best practice" does.  Both are excuses for people to turn their brains off.  Don't accept anyone telling you something is a "best practice" or an "anti-pattern" if they can't explain the reasons why.

Answer (score 14):

Alternative perspective - focus on the exceptions and what they represent to the exception's source, rather than `try..except`.

Eric Lippert in his [Blog](https://ericlippert.com/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/) describes 4 broad categories of Exceptions, summarised below.

> ##### Fatal
>
> - **Definition**: Fatal exceptions are not yor fault, and you cannot sensibly clean up from them.
> - **Examples**: Out of memory, thread aborted.
> - **Resolution**: Don’t catch; let them crash the program.
> - **Design**: Don’t ever throw fatal exceptions directly.
>
> ##### Boneheaded
>
> - **Definition**: Boneheaded exceptions are violations of the API, and are bugs in your code.
> - **Examples**: Argument is null, index out of range.
> - **Resolution**: Don’t catch; fix them in the code.
> - **Design**: Use code contracts for boneheaded exceptions; do not document the specific exception type.
>
> ##### Vexing
>
> - **Definition**: Vexing exceptions are due to bad design decisions, thrown in non-exceptional situations.
> - **Examples**: Parsing errors.
> - **Resolution**: Avoid calling vexing functions; if not possible, catch the vexing exception.
> - **Design**: Don’t ever throw vexing exceptions.
>
> ##### Exogenous
>
> - **Definition**: Exogenous exceptions are from unpredictable, external influences.
> - **Examples**: File not found, resource already in use.
> - **Resolution**: Always catch and handle.
> - **Design**: Throw exogenous exceptions as necessary; document the specific exception type.

Obviously this just focuses on the exceptions themselves there are other important considerations around code which uses exceptions, including:

- If any type of exception cannot be gracefully handled and recovered, ensure the full exception information is logged, including as much information around it as possible.
- If a framework you're using doesn't record unhandled exceptions, include a top-level 'catch-all' near `main` which can generate a crashdump with that information.
- Use unit tests to assert when exceptions are expected to be thrown and when they are expected to be handled.

Answer (score 10):

Try/except is not an antipattern, although it is probably an antipattern to turn an error condition into a boolean. But this happens in both examples, so that is a separate question.

Both status codes and exceptions are valid ways to handle HTTP error responses. The choice is a question of abstraction level.

If you are writing networking-level code (e.g. a proxy server), you probably want to treat all status codes on the same level of abstraction. A 4xx or 5xx status does not mean your program cannot fulfill its task, it is just a response which have to be handled appropriately.

If you are writing application level code, e.g some business logic which perform HTTP requests to fetch data, you want to separate network-level error conditions from the regular application logic, and exceptions are appropriate.

There are two separate questions: When is it appropriate to *throw* an exception, and when it is appropriate to *catch* an exception?

It is appropriate to throw an exception when a condition occurs which cannot be meaningfully handled at the level of abstraction of the current function. Of course this requires functions to be clear about abstraction levels, which might be the harder problem. Consider a function called `sendHttpRequest(url, method, payload)`. A HTTP response code would be at the same level, so it would be reasonable to have as part of the return value.

But consider the function `getCurrentExchangeRate(fromCurreny, toCurrency)` which internally calls some HTTP service. Clients calling this method would not be expected to know about HTTP response codes. It would therefore be appropriate for the function to throw an exception if it for whatever reason is not able to return the exchange rate.

Exceptions should only be *caught* when code is able to meaningfully handle the condition. If an exception cannot be handled at any level, then it should be allowed to rise to the top and terminate the application (*fail fast* principle).

*Handling* an exception means the code should be able to continue without fear of any state being corrupted by the operations which were not completed. (For example, returning 0 for the missing exchange rate would *not* be an appropriate way to handle the error, since this just leads to data corruption down the line. If in doubt, always fail fast.)

Catching an exception and returning false would almost never be a useful way to handle an exception or error condition, since it doesn't provide any information about what went wrong, and therefore no reasonable way for callers to handle the problem. A HTTP request could fail because of intermittent network errors, or it could fail because a hardcoded URL has a typo. These errors should be handled differently - network errors could be handled by re-trying the request, while the typo *should* fail fast, alerting developers to the problem.

Comment: Thank you!  This is very helpful (+1) and I agree.  I further agree with you that it is probably an antipattern to turn an error into a boolean.  In fact, that is something else I raised with this team, and was met with pushback (they prefer this).  It seems like a bad idea, to me.  Knowing that I agree, why would you say that it's a bad pattern?

Comment: @Daniel it really depends on the context, but in general, turning error conditions into boolean status codes is bad because you lose information about the cause of the error, so there is no way to handle the error appropriately in code or give useful feedback to the user.

Comment: Makes total sense to me.  Thanks for the ideas; I'll try and express that to my team and see if I can change their mind about this.  Thank you!

Comment: this is one of the better answers I've seen on the topic. could recommend any further reading on it?

Answer (score 1):

To understand why it's bad you have to take a holistic view of the calling code and the function together.

```
func doThing()
{
    try:
        resp.fetch(URL)
        return true;
    except HTTPError as e:
        logging.info("HTTP request failed with error: ", e)
        return False
}

main() 
{
    var result = doThing();
    if(result)
    {
        //continue with other things
    }
    else
    {
        //log an error and move to some other branch?
    }
}
```

Now consider a simplified version:

```
func doThing()
{
    resp.fetch(URL)
}

main() 
{
    try:
        doThing(); 
        //continue with other things           
    except Error as e:
        logging.error("Error happened!", e)        
}
```

You can see the second version is just better. You have less conditions and if exceptions are exceptional you could even get rid of the try catch and have some sort of global error handler.

I would sum up the general rules as follows

1. Don't catch and return false when you could let the exception bubble up instead.
2. Don't log in low level functions, let the exception bubble and log at the top level.
3. Don't swallow exceptions and continue unless the failure is expected. ie. a known bad network connection, or you have a list of things and you know some will fail.

Second question. Is the original function your colleagues wrote good?

```
resp = fetch(URL)
if resp.status_code != 200:
    return False
```

Here, unlike in your code, it looks like fetch won't throw an exception when non success codes are returned. so they have added this check and return false.

However, if we look at the calling code again, that means we have to check the result is true everytime, leading to lots of needless conditional statements.

It would be better to throw an exception instead which allows the more simple way of calling the function.

```
MyObject DoThing()
{
    resp = fetch(URL)
    if resp.status_code != 200:
        throw "Error connecting to resource"
    return ResultParser.Parse<MyObject>(resp.body);  //whatever code you need to parse the response
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, most every modern http client library has a way to raise exceptions based on status code. Even hardcore functional programming libraries like [http4s](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.http4s/http4s-docs_2.13/0.23.18/org/http4s/client/Client.html) provide an API that raises an error in your IO monad instead of forcing an explicit check. If it were an anti-pattern, it wouldn't be so prevalent.

Exceptions exist in the first place because most production code has one "happy path" and one or more other paths. These are separate concerns that are easier to code if you have a mechanism like exceptions that allows you to separate them, especially if you are composing several steps that each have multiple paths.

For exceptions to be beneficial, you need to actually use them to separate concerns. If you're just setting a boolean whether your request succeeds or fails, the exception doesn't help you. You'd have to restructure some of the calling code so handling non-2xx status codes is consolidated in one place, and handling json parse errors of the response body is consolidated in one place, and application-level errors are consolidated in one place, and the happy path code isn't frequently interrupted by error handling code.

That means in general if your `try` only covers one line of code and your `catch` is in the same method, the exception isn't usually buying you anything, and it's costing you some code simplicity and some stack unwinding time.

In summary, don't try to think of exceptions as being "rare" things, but as separate concerns that you don't want interrupting your main flow.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I am with your colleague. Not using exception here is cheap, while using it is not. So why would you like to use it?

Currently my design principle is as follows -- is an error a completely surprise to me/code/design? If yes -- use exception, if not -- use "error token".

And currently my error token consists of -- severity, message, source and optionally failure data.

Such design allows to be more forgiving when running code, but strict when running tests, also it is much better to bubble up the most crucial error up.

Answer (score 0):

Use exceptions for exceptional situations. When you request a URL, the following are not exceptional:

1. No internet connection at all.
2. Cannot find the server in question.
3. Cannot establish a secure connection to the server.
4. Malformed resource name.
5. Request times out.
6. Status code telling you that the server made a request timing out.
7. Resource not found.
8. No permission to access resource
9. Missing authentication for resource
10. User cancelled the operation
11. Operation wasn’t allowed to proceed because it required a user interaction.

and many others.

MacOS and iOS distinguish between errors (anything happened that stopped you from getting a response from the server), and status codes (client received a status code from the server).

It is usually best to have *one* method that attempts a download, handles any problems in a suitable way, and returns either success with the data downloaded, success with no data downloaded, or failure, so all complex error handling needs to be written only once.

Answer (score -2):

It really depends on the context/design. A non-200 status doesn't necessarily have to raise an exception in your code unless it's designed that way. Regardless, it's still possible to get an exception for something else like no network connection, or the request timed out. You can either handle those in your code, or they may be getting handled elsewhere and by design your code is expected to ignore handling them.

You don't mention it, but this looks like Python. Python 3.11 came out with "zero cost" exception handling[1](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/84403), so if part of your colleagues reason is performance, maybe that can be less of an issue in the future?

I'd probably try to do something like this:

```py
try:
    resp.fetch(URL)
    if resp.status_code == "":
        # Make sure that there is/was a status code
        raise NoStatusCodeException
    elif resp.status_code != 200:
        return False
except KnownException as e:
    # Known issue that I want to generally ignore and still handle with return False
    logging.debug("Return False, ignore KnownException: ", e)
    return False
except Exception as e:
    # Unexpected issue that should be reviewed
    logging.error("Unexpected exception: ", e)
    return False
```

Comment: Both Google and apple have specific URLs for checking whether you are connected to a captive network. And these URLs will return very specific and unusual status codes. So say 202 may not be any problem at all.

Answer (score -3):

HTTP was not made with exceptions in mind. It predates the OO-era. It is pointless to map HTTP status codes to exceptions. None of them can be considered "exceptional" or errors in the sense that something went wrong in your program. So I don't think exception handling is helpful here, it is just confusing and mixes mutually exclusive paradigms.

Comment: 4xx and 5xx status codes are called "errors" (client errors and server errors) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status.  How should one harmonize what your answer says with how that link (among many other resources) characterizes those status codes?

Comment: @Daniel I was explicit about this. They are not "errors in the sense that something went wrong in your program". HTTP may call it an error, to your client application they are just some of many possible and expected responses.

Comment: hm...could I trouble you to help me better understand your point?  if I expect that this call to fetch will succeed (i.e., return a 200), and it doesn't succeed, how is that not something that went wrong in my program?  What if I claim that any response other than 200 IS something that went wrong? (i.e., not the way my program was expected to run?) is my point of view incorrect?  I see what you are saying that there are many possible responses, but would you agree that some responses are desirable and others not (ie., success and exception)?

Comment: @Daniel You got your response and all is well, you can switch your way out of there. Throwing after you get a perfectly valid response, handling the exception and then returning a result value after all defeats the purpose of using exceptions.

Comment: ahh OK, I see what you are saying.  Thank you very much for explaining!

Comment: This answer is a bit inaccurate. Status codes appeared in the [1992 HTTP draft](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTTP2.html). Try-catch style exception handling was developed in the 70s in the Lisp community. Exceptions went mainstream later. C++ designed exceptions between 1986 and 1990, though implementation/uptake was lagging, and they were later popularized with Java. Berners-Lee was well aware of OOP (first browser was coded in Objective-C), but exceptions weren't yet part of that. However, you're entirely correct that status codes are not errors as far as the HTTP protocol is concerned.